# npm install constantly errors out with "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ..." but it's always something different

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have tried to `npm install` a project several times that my coworkers have no problem installing. Every single time I try, I get "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '" and then an output. That output changes every single time.

I do an `npm cache clean --force` and then try to `npm install` again and somewhere along the line I inevitably get that same `Unexpected end of JSON` error, but with a new string at the end of the line.

I'm at my wits and can't find any information on the issue online.

Comment: Are you using the same versions of node and npm as your colleagues?

Comment: I'm using the latest version as I think they are too.

Would that cause this kind of error?

Comment: Couple of things I found, not sure if you saw them.. [this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/990#issuecomment-395750082) and [this](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/990#issuecomment-527004654)

Comment: I faced similar issue. Searched for a solution but found all suggestions with `npm cache clean --force` then uninstalling angular and reinstall but nothing worked. To fix it I had to go in to the app folder and do `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install`, kept on repeating until all the packages were installed and got the app running.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can works. do it step by step.

```
npm config set strict-ssl false

npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port

npm config set https-proxy https://proxy.company.com:8080

npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```